# Error Trying To Use Google AdMob With SwiftUI - Can Not Find *.plist

Tags: xcode, swiftui, admob, plist, simulator

```
Google AdMob 9.11.0
XCode 14.0.1
XCode Simulator 14.0.1
Simulated Device iPhone 14 Pro Max
Simulated Device OS iOS 16
```

I am new to Google AdMob. I have a dummy app and have added the required XCFrameworks and updated my plist (in the info section of the project settings, which creates a *.plist file with just the custom *.plist entries). When I try and build and run the app without really any Google AdMob code, it complies clean, but then fails trying to load the app to the simulator. It does the same with any simulator version I choose, and the same on my native device (which is an Xr). Here is the error I get in XCode;

Unable To Install AdMobTest - Please try again later.

`Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /Users/gar/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/73AB96E0-A18C-48EC-AC15-F7D8A703FDC4/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.AFlmNx/extracted/AdMobTest.app/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework; Extra info about "/Users/gar/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/73AB96E0-A18C-48EC-AC15-F7D8A703FDC4/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.AFlmNx/extracted/AdMobTest.app/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Info.plist": Couldn't stat /Users/gar/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/73AB96E0-A18C-48EC-AC15-F7D8A703FDC4/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.AFlmNx/extracted/AdMobTest.app/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Info.plist: No such file or directory"`

It looks like XCode is failing to propigate the *.plist to the target device, but I have no idea why. Does anyone have any idea why this would be the case, or have seen this before. I am not sure it is really a AdMob issue so much as it is a custom *.plist entry issue, but I am not sure.

Here is the *.plist in question (in full).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>GADApplicationIdentifier</key>
    <string>ca-app-pub-....</string>
    <key>SKAdNetworkItems</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>cstr6suwn9.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>4fzdc2evr5.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>2fnua5tdw4.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>ydx93a7ass.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>5a6flpkh64.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>p78axxw29g.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>v72qych5uu.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>c6k4g5qg8m.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>s39g8k73mm.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>3qy4746246.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>3sh42y64q3.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>f38h382jlk.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>hs6bdukanm.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>prcb7njmu6.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>v4nxqhlyqp.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>wzmmz9fp6w.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>yclnxrl5pm.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>t38b2kh725.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>7ug5zh24hu.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>9rd848q2bz.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>n6fk4nfna4.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>kbd757ywx3.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>9t245vhmpl.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>4468km3ulz.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>2u9pt9hc89.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>8s468mfl3y.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>av6w8kgt66.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>klf5c3l5u5.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>ppxm28t8ap.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>424m5254lk.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>uw77j35x4d.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>578prtvx9j.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>4dzt52r2t5.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>e5fvkxwrpn.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>8c4e2ghe7u.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>zq492l623r.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>3qcr597p9d.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Thanks in advance for any help, pointers, ideas, or links you can provide. Have a great day.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm having the same now with Xcode 15.3

Comment: @hotdogsoup.nl - The problem just vanished with another update of Xcode and hence I suspect a bug in Xcode, but I never proved that. I too have an issue with an app that has AdMob with Xcode 15.3. I went back to 15.2 and the problem vanished. I won't be upgrading to 15.3 till it gets fixed.